# oracle pl/sql how to replicate more than one tables' data

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am having a scenario where my `oracle` db has some 20 tables, all have an index field called **itemId**.
I want to copy records with an id (called 101)  from all 20 tables and insert them with a new id (called 102). 
I don't want to have 20 cursors or 20 `functions/procedures` because the table list may grow in future. help me to achieve this in a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have a potentially variable number of tables, you will need to use dynamic SQL to achieve your aim.  Something like the following should hopefully help:

```
DECLARE
  l_insert_column_list      VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_select_column_list      VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  FOR table_rec IN (SELECT table_name
                      FROM user_tab_columns
                     WHERE UPPER(column_name) = 'ITEMID')
  LOOP
    l_insert_column_list := '';
    l_select_column_list := '';
    FOR col_rec IN (SELECT column_name
                      FROM user_tab_columns
                     WHERE table_name = table_rec.table_name)
    LOOP
      l_insert_column_list := l_insert_column_list || col_rec.column_name || ',';
      IF UPPER(col_rec.column_name) = 'ITEMID' THEN
        l_select_column_list := l_select_column_list || '102,';
      ELSE
        l_select_column_list := l_select_column_list || col_rec.column_name || ',';
      END IF;
    END LOOP;

    l_insert_column_list := RTRIM(l_insert_column_list, ',');
    l_select_column_list := RTRIM(l_select_column_list, ',');

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || table_rec.table_name || ' (' 
        || l_insert_column_list || ') SELECT ' || l_select_column_list ||
        ' FROM ' || table_rec.table_name || ' WHERE ITEMID = 101';

  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

The idea here is to use the `user_tab_columns` data dictionary view to list all of the tables that have an `ITEMID` column.  For each such table we then use `user_tab_columns` to list all of the columns in the table and then build up a SQL string to copy the data.

I've made a few assumptions here:

- All of your tables are in the same schema.  If not, you might need to use `all_tab_columns` instead of `user_tab_columns`, and include the schema owner in `table_rec` and in the SQL strings where `table_rec.table_name` is also used.
- None of your table or column names have names that need to be enclosed in double quotes.  (If they do, you'll have to adjust the SQL strings to include double quotes.)
- 4000 characters is enough for all of the column names in your tables.  (As column names are limited to 30 characters, you'd need over 100 columns to trigger this problem.)

Before you let this script loose on your database, I would strongly recommend replacing `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` with a call to `dbms_output.put_line` so that you can see the SQL strings that are being generated.